# What is the ion drag mechanism in dielectric heating?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, heat, water, dielectric

While reading about [dielectric heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating) on Wikipedia, I read about the ion drag mechanism but there wasn't enough information about.

I know there is another Phys.SE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23064/2451) talking about the ion drag in heating but the answer isn't explaining the mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ion-drag mechanism refers to heat generation whose microscopic origin is the momentum transfer in collisions, between a flux of charged particles [ions] and other charged species, induced by the Coulomb force.

Comment: What does it have to do with dielectric heating and microwaves?

Comment: Inelastic collisions between particles produce kinetic energy losses that turn into vibrational energy of the particles [heat]. The microwaves are simply time-dependent electric fields which produce the Coulomb drag.

Comment: Why then ions are dragged slowly ?

Comment: Because the EM frequency is low. If the EM frequency is too high the ions oscillate so quickly that there is no displacement but vibration.

Answer (score 0):

Ion drag is associated with low frequency (RF) EM waveforms, and is what causes resistive heating, not dielectric heating. Dielectric heating (e.g. microwaves) relies on dipole rotation.